# Log.d with ActionBarScherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, logcat

I am trying to get a handle on LogCat by adding some code from a textbook example to one of my projects.

My project uses ABS

When I try and use:

```
    @Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,"onPause() called");
}
```

I am running into the error

> TAG has private access in 'com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity'

Why is this, and how can I get around it? I've had a search around on Google but not found anything relating to this.

Comment: where is TAG declared?

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked the most basic issue!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a private field `TAG` in the parent `SherlockFragmentActivity` and you cannot use it.

Instead, you should specify your own tag in your class, e.g.

```
private static final String TAG = YourActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Log.d(String param1, String param2)`  takes two parameters :

- `param1` : a string used as a tag to identify your logs in Logcat
- `param2` : a second string which is the message to show in your log

Example :

```
Log.d("MY APP LOG", "This is the message of my app's log");
```

So replace `TAG` with a simple string, or create it as a `Constant` inside your class :

```
private static final String TAG = "MY_TAG";
```

The error you get : `TAG has private access in 'com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity'` means that there's a non `public` variable TAG you are trying to access.